# 2+2=2 in C (double arithmetics)

Tags: c, double, sum

I have absolutely no idea why it returns `2` for `a=2` and `b=2`..

Any ideas?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double a,b,c;
    printf("a=");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("b=");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("c=");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    printf("x=%d", a+b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question has been answered, but you also have another error. You're including `stdlib.h`, but `printf` and `scanf` are not defined in `stdlib.h`. You need `stdio.h`. By the way, your compiler really ought to have issued warnings for all of these problems. Did you read its output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specifier `"%d"` expects an integer and you are passing the address of a `double`. Using the wrong specifiers in `scanf` leads to undefined behavior.

Also, using the wrong specifier in `printf` is the same thing. Because `printf` takes a variable number of arguments `a + b` which is a double can't be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is for reading integers, use `%f` or `%lf` for float/double.

Answer (score 1):

printf should use something like `%f` instead of `%d`. The same for scanf.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept a float input, use `scanf` (and `printf`) with the `%lf` formatting character, not `%d` (which is for integers).

The behavior of your current program is undefined, since the scanf calls are writing an integer to a float variable. Also, you're missing `include <stdio.h>` at the top of your program. To catch errors like these, turn on the warnings in your C compiler:

```
$ gcc so-scanf.c -Wall
so-scanf.c: In function ‘main’:
so-scanf.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
so-scanf.c:6:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
so-scanf.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘scanf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
so-scanf.c:7:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’ [enabled by default]
so-scanf.c:7:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat]
so-scanf.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat]
so-scanf.c:11:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat]
so-scanf.c:13:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat]
```

Comment: You need %lf for doubles with scanf